# mpdf - get content (written by JS) on post

Tags: javascript, php, json, pdf, mpdf

I am trying to generate PDF on post because the content is populated by JSON services...

```
if (isset($_POST['printpdf']))
{
$html = ob_get_contents();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->Output();
exit;   
}
```

The pdf generated only have hardcoded data (i.e labels) because mPDF is server side and data is populated with JS on client side.

How can I get JSON populated data on mPDF generated PDF?